# Ping sometimes works and sometimes fails

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a Cloud Core Router with v6.1 RouterOs. It has defined a PPPoE client, add-default-route to yes and masquerade to out interface.

I can ping the router from any device connected to the internet but when i ping from the Mikrotik console to my router connected to providers (Juniper M20), ping sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

The PPPoE server is a cisco 7206VXR router (previously an Imagestream). 
The initial configuration that was working in the Mikrotik had two WAN connections, one for hotspot clients and the other one for the office. This worked for 2 weeks without problems but one day stopped working. I deleted one of the connection with this one and sometimes i have this problem .

What could be the cause? Any suggestion?

Here is a picture showing the network scheme

[image: Network Diagram]

The PPPoE session is always up, and the rest of the clients have normal behavior but the mikrotik router sometimes can ping to Router_2 and sometimes can't. We have changed the router for a new one and the problem persists. We have a radio link to the location where the mikrotik is and another PPPoE session with another router (Linksys) working without this issue at the same place... but the radio link has two ethernet interfaces acting as switch, one for each ppp client. So we suspect it could be the radio link if network configuration seems to be correct...

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what you are asking.  Can you reword the question -- ping from where to where?  Can you provide some configurations and maybe a simple diagram?  That would help us give you an answer.

Comment: Mikrotik is Router_2 or PPP_Client? Try ping PPPoE remote address.

Comment: At "Mikrotik PPP client", whant mean "ip route 0.0.0.0/0 via PPPoE out"? It's manual added static route or dynamic (and You just confirm working add-default-route=yes)?

Also try get "/ip route print" when it work and when not.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Some more detail would be in order, intermittent faults are frequently caused by external factors & simple answers can become elusive.  Rule out physical connection issues first.   Specifically if you ping the router & it responds for NNN tries (no loss & consistent reply time), you know the cable plant is sound at least for now.  Likewise when it fails, how it responds (actual timeout errors or TTL expiration, some replies only or excessive times) is just as important & may indicate wiring or connector quality.

As always take good notes & don't write off the scientific method.  You've already eliminated the router itself but consider resetting the device during these tests.  If you can trigger an event where the connection drops (or had failed & now works), trap the logs for review.  Of course if you suspect the radio link arrange a time to eliminate that during the outage, off-hours if necessary to avoid business impact.